# Meteor Mongo collection multiple queries

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm wondering if this is possible to do with Mongo/Meteor:

I've a collection, and documents all included a createdAt field and a status field (true/false boolean). I want to show users this collection in a list but only with documents that match:

`if status is false AND if status is true only those before 14 days ago.`

I can filter the list based on the two fields the way I want separately in my template helper, but how do I combine both restrictions together into one collection on the client side?

---

Update: so I think I am looking for an `or` statement as Patrick mentioned however it doesn't seem to work.

```
var date = new Date(+new Date - 12096e5);
    return Things.find({$and: [
        { $or : [ { status : false } ] },
        { $or : [ { status : true } , { createdAt: {"$gte": date} } ] }
    ]},
        {sort:{createdAt:-1}});
```

Doh, I have `and` and `or` backwards! I want items that match either of the two and conditions to be returned back and the below seems to work.

```
var date = new Date(+new Date - 12096e5);
    return Things.find({$or: [
        { $and : [ { status : false } ] },
        { $and : [ { status : true } , { createdAt: {"$gte": date} } ] }
    ]},
        {sort:{createdAt:-1}});
```

Comment: Don't you mean `OR` here? You're looking for the union of these two statements, right?

Comment: Yes I guess I am looking for an `or`... `false` `or` `true within last 14 days`

Comment: Your solution looks correct except for two points: you don't need the `$and`s and I think you may mean `$lte` if you want a date prior to 14 days.

Comment: Why don't I need the `$and`s? For the first one I can see not needing it, but the second set needs to match both, will a comma suffice? And I need only those that that are within the last 14 days, so from 14 days ago up until today, the ones before that can be excluded.

Comment: mongodb has an implicit [AND](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) for comma-separated expressions.

Answer (score 2):

As Patrick mentioned I wanted and `or` statement, with an `and` to combine the set of two requirements, the below code works. Improved with help of David

```
var date = new Date(+new Date - 12096e5);
    return Things.find({$or: [
        { status : false },
        { status : true , createdAt: {"$gte": date} }
    ]},
        {sort:{createdAt:-1}});
```